# Why isn't std::array's operator==() marked constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, comparison, constexpr, stdarray

It's [very natural](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) to want to compare `std::array`'s at compile time; and its `operator==()` is obviously `constexpr`'able. Yet - it [isn't](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp) marked `constexpr`. Is this intentional or an oversight? And - what's the reason it was left that way (apparently in C++17 as well)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[P0031](https://wg21.link/P0031) explained why it didn't propose `constexpr` comparisons:

> Currently comparisons and `swap`/`fill` may be implemented with the help
>   of algorithms from `<algorithm>` header. Marking comparisons with
>   constexpr will break that ability and will potentially lead to
>   performance degradations.

For example, `==` can be implemented in terms of `std::equal`, which - in appropriate cases - can call the highly-optimized-but-decidedly-not-`constexpr`  `memcmp`. Making `constexpr` for `==` will rule out this optimization without special compiler assistance.

Comment: Daniel Kruger says: This may be resolved when/if proposal [P0202](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0202r1.html) is adopted.

Answer (score -2):

The rationale might be this: `==` of an array can only be a `constexpr` if the contained type's `==` is a `constexpr`, too.

Since the container can't enforce that, it can't (generally) offer a `operator==() constexpr`.

Comment: The first sentence is true for any templated constexpr function which does anything with its template parameter. And - those can very well be made `constexpr`... so that is not it. (PS - Not my downvote.)

Comment: I'm having a hard time thinking of a templated constexpr function that deserves that name and deals with non-constexpr type members...

Comment: @MarcusMüller `constexpr` for a templated function does not mean that the function is always `constexpr`, it just say this function may be `constexpr` for some types.